# what is the username and password for the cosmos db emulator

Tags: azure, local, azure-cosmosdb

I try to import a bunch of JSON files into cosmos db emulator, so localhost. Ik try to do this using the DocumentDB Data Migration Tool. 
Before anyone says that the tool is not working for cosmos db. According to Microsoft it should work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data

But my problem is I can't connect to my local emulator. I tried Googling, but I can't find a right connection string for the tool to work. Any one any idea what the connection string for local emulator is? Or the username and password?

Comment: See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator (search the page for `Key`)

Comment: Thank you very much, I've bin there more than 100 times and didn't see that-_-. I need a rubber duck.

Comment: You can self-answer your question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @Peter B!

```
Account name: localhost:<port>
Account key: C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
```

Found at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator

Answer (score 2):

The username of Cosmosdb emulator account is localhost.And its password is the Primary Key mentioned in the Quickstart blade in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

The connection string for your app can be

```
AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
```

If you navigate to https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html, you can find all the details.

[image]

Make sure emulator is running to navigate to the url and use the url in chrome, firefox gives some wierd ssl error.

Comment: `import azureStorage from "azure-storage";

const endpoint = 'AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==';
const tableService = azureStorage.createTableService(endpoint);`

When I try above code for typescript, its giving error "Connection string contains unrecognized key: "AccountEndpoint""

Comment: Which package you use to connect to cosmosdb

Comment: azure storage package