# What is the username of cosmosdb emulator account?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are provided with the username of our azure Cosmos Db account in Connection String blade in azure portal. But no details about the username is provided for Cosmos Db emulator. Only a key is provided which is the password. How can we know the username of Cosmos Db emulator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the username and password for the cosmos db emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814786/what-is-the-username-and-password-for-the-cosmos-db-emulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we know the username of Cosmos Db emulator?

In the emulator UI, `URI` is the `username` you want to get.

[image]

You could connect emulator client using URI and Primary Key,or you could use Connection String directly.

Just for summary, if you use java sdk to access cosmos emulator,don't forget exporting ssl cert step. For node js sdk ,no need to do that because SSL verification is disabled for python and node js sdk. More details ,please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#differences-between-the-emulator-and-the-service).

Comment: By trying to use URI as username i got the Authentication error.URI is not same as Username in my opinion.

Comment: The username of Cosmos DB Emulator is localhost by default.Note that here localhost doesn't refer to the IP address of the local machine.The Emulator sets the username as localhost by default.

Comment: @VarunKumar So,have you tried export ssl cert from this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#running-on-windows? You already solved the auth issue?

Comment: I didn't export SSL certificate while connecting to Cosmos DB Emulator using Nodejs. It connected without any issue. But when I tried to connect to the Emulator using Java,it couldn't connect. After exporting the certificate to JVM Trust Certificate list, I was able to connect to the Emulator.

Comment: @VarunKumar Ok,great. I summarized some updates in my answer. Would you please mark it to end this case,that could provide some references for others on the forum. Thanks  a lot.